# IllegalStateException When I try to query my database from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am developing an application to schedule payment dates, one of its functions is to send you a notification on each date that you must make your payments. To achieve this, I check daily if it is a payment date, if so, I activate the notification so that it is shown later.

The application is already in production and the Play Console tells me that the following error has occurred 90 times:

Type: java.lang.RuntimeException

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3990)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:233)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2006)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:241)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7582)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:492)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:941)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade (RoomOpenHelper.java:117)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:177)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:417)
  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (SQLiteOpenHelper.java:317)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:145)
  at androidx.sqlite.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase (FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:106)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.inTransaction (RoomDatabase.java:622)
  at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction (RoomDatabase.java:399)
  at com.mypackagename.crud.PaymentDao_Impl.getPaymentsOfDate (PaymentDao_Impl.java:447)
  at com.mypackagename.AlarmReceiver.aviactivateTodayReminders (AlarmReceiver.java:95)
  at com.mypackagename.AlarmReceiver.onReceive (AlarmReceiver.java:35)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3981)
```

I don't know what the problem could be but I have read that other people have had problems accessing the database from BroadcastReceiver, am I doing something wrong? This is my code:

**AlarmReceiver:**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

static AppDataBase appDataBase;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (appDataBase == null){
        appDataBase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDataBase.class, Constants.DB_NAME)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
    }

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action != null && context != null) {
        if("ACTIVATOR".equals(action)) {
            aviactivateTodayReminders(context, appDataBase);
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {//Reactivate after restart
            NotificationScheduler.enableDailyActivator(context);
            aviactivateTodayReminders(context, appDataBase);
            return;
        }
    }

    if (action == null){//Show notification
        //Code omitted for better understanding...
    }
}

static void aviactivateTodayReminders(Context context, AppDataBase appDataBase){//Enable today's notifications
    List<Long> idPaymentList = appDataBase.paymentDao().getPaymentsOfDate(todayDate());
    for (int i = 0; i < idPaymentList.size(); i++){
        long idPayment = idPaymentList.get(i);
        NotificationScheduler.setNotification(context, (int) idPayment);
    }
}

static String todayDate(){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return dateFormat.format(new Date());
}
```

}

**getPaymentsOfDate:**

```
@Query("SELECT _id FROM Payment WHERE date =:xDate ")
List<Long> getPaymentsOfDate(String xDate);
```

**Notification Scheduler** (I don't see a need to include it but here it is)

```
public class NotificationScheduler {

public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "10000";

static void enableDailyActivator(Context context){//Enable activator service
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction("ACTIVATOR");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Calendar cHourActivation = Calendar.getInstance();
    cHourActivation.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Constants.HOUR_ACTIVATION);
    cHourActivation.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cHourActivation.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cHourActivation.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    if (cHourActivation.getTimeInMillis() <= System.currentTimeMillis())
        cHourActivation.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.cancel(pendingIntent);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cHourActivation.getTimeInMillis(), (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), pendingIntent);
}

public static void setNotification(Context context, int idPayment){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("idPayment", idPayment);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, idPayment, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(pendingIntent);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    } else {
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
}

public static void showNotification(Context context, String title, String content, int idTanda){
    //Code omitted for better understanding...
}
```

}

Important details:

- EnableDailyActivator runs when starting the application for the first time and restarting the device.
- "ACTIVATOR" It should be executed every day at approximately 00:00, this will call the aviactivateTodayReminders method that aims to obtain (from the database) the id of the current day's payments to schedule the notifications, unfortunately there is the error I see in Play Console

  `List<Long> idPaymentList = appDataBase.paymentDao().getPaymentsOfDate(todayDate());`

What is the origin of the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Please stop doing disk I/O on the main application thread, let alone from `onReceive()` of a `BroadcastReceiver`. Please use your `BroadcastReceiver` to schedule some work in `WorkManager` to do your disk I/O and the results from that I/O.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I have implemented it as you told me, I don't know why I can't choose your answer as accepted